# Defining panel.args length in a trellis.object

Tags: list, indexing, ls

Good evening everybody,
a very simple question: I have created a trellis object with a list of plots like this

```
ls(grafico.PAX)
 [1] "HT00027074" "HT00041471" "HT00042977" "HT00044297" "HT00044352" "HT00044735" "HT00046016"
[8] "HT00047780" "HT00049362" "HT00055644" "HT00055649" "HT00058023" "HT00058172" "HT00058650"
[15] "HT00061221" "HT00061283" "HT00061952" "HT00062062" "HT00067896" "HT00068212" "HT00068231"
[22] "HT00068665" "HT00070389" "HT00071625" "HT00071640" "HT00071705" "HT00071768" "HT00071998"
[29] "HT00072343" "HT00078488" "HT00078520" "HT00078735" "HT00078775" "HT00078796" "HT00079322"
[36] "HT00079921" "HT00081229" "HT00081484" "HT00081490" "HT00081519" "HT00081695" "HT00081784"
[43] "HT00081788" "HT00081800" "HT00081897" "HT00081899" "HT00082062" "HT00082426" "HT00082569"
[50] "HT00082589" "HT00082637" "HT00082638" "HT00082885"
```

and I would like to know how many elements are there in the `panel.args` list of each of the `grafico.PAX` elements.
I have tried to get it in several ways, and I don't have a clue...

Thanks in advance,
MZ

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the last option was the right one (and I didn't check before posting! too bad from me!):

```
length(grafico.PAX[[1]]$panel.args)
```

Thanks again,
MZ